# Identifying a flex ribbon connector

Tags: surface-mount

I'm trying to identify what this type of connector is. The first image is the male connector, attached to a flex ribbon. It has 20 pins on each side. I thought it was an FFC connector, but can't find anything remotely like it in Digikey FFC connectors. The closest match I can find is an Apple LCD flex cable "grade R" replacement. Any ideas? Thanks!

[image: Male Connector]

[image: Female connector]

Comment: Looks like a thousand other interconnects I've seen.

Comment: Note that many manufacturers make similar-looking board-to-board connectors, but they are incompatible between them. Also, some chinese manufacturers make some that are unavailable on mouser/digikey and don't publish datasheets to the public. You may have trouble finding the exact part you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

They're "board to board" connectors, but are sometimes used on FPC as well - especially for things like TFT.

I am not sure of that specific model, but I use a similar one from Hirose (DF30FC-20DS-0.4V(82)).
[image]

It's not quite identical, but it should give you a starting point.

This is one used on the Picadillo-35T board which looks a closer match:

[image]

Unfortunately I don't have a model number for that, though with a bit of pestering I may be able to find out.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you identify the pitch, but the magic sauce search terms to get some hits on suppliers seem to be "btb" and/or "slimstack". Foxxcon has a board-to-board connector, but seems to be a different set of dimensions from the standard black ones I find in most tablets/phones these days.

I know it's a old post, but [here is the Molex site](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/slimstack_fine_pitch_smt_board_to_board_connectors?parentKey=board_to_board_connectors) highlighting some standard looking board-to-board and board-to-FPC connectors, hopefully it'll help someone track down parts.